# Local search doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to search a list item in SharePoint 2013. We have +5000 items. I am using the following JS, but I found an error when I debug it(Uncaught ReferenceError: search is not defined).

```
<input type="text" style="width:350px" id="txtSearch" /><input type="button" style=" font-size:15px;font-family:'Segoe UI Light','Segoe UI','Segoe',Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#0072C6; color:white" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return search();" />
```